# MvvmCross iOS dependency for .Net 3.5?

Tags: ios, .net, mvvmcross

I am trying to determine/understand if I need to reference the .Net 3.5 library in Xamarin for iOS projects.

Each time I open up a solution that contains a MonoTouch project for iOS I am prompted to include the .NET Framework 3.5.  I would prefer not to intall this if possible.  I can see that some of the Cirrious.MvvmCross dlls such as Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch are dependent upon Runtime Version of v2.0.50727 - and I guess this is why it is probably prompting me.  However, I can quite happily ignore the reference and it will work.

I would like to know what I can't do if I don't include the .Net 3.5 (2.n etc) so that I can safely ignore the dependency.

Secondly - if I can ignore this dependency - how do I go about this?

Thanks

Alan.

Comment: Sounds like a Xamarin pcl error somewhere in your setup - maybe try reaching out to them for support.

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  I did, but the response was not really applicable.  it seems that only the iOS project needs the libraries so I will include in that project specifically.  The way that Xamarin builds the iOS app I am thinking that it will not really matter in the end.  If it needs something specific from the older runtimes then it will grab the code and include in the runtime for the Apple install.